# failed find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: application-development, android, environment-variables, ubuntu-sdk

I know this is quite a common question being asked and this below seems to give a detailed explanation but the thing is, I still couldn't get my sdk running why? (still really new with linux hierarchy and installations)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198165/failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable

I have followed a few threads to put the `$ANDROID_HOME` and `$PATH` into my `~/.bash_profile` but just wouldn't work.

I am starting to doubt if I am putting the correct directory. (Even though I tried pretty much all and still no luck)

I downloaded SDK from and SDK development site and extract the folder into `/home/et-ubuntu-pc/App/` the folder extracted is named `android-studio` and this is the location which I expect my studio is installed after I went into `/home/et-ubuntu-pc/App/android-studio/bin/` and ran `/.studio.sh` but in the other forums they keep on saying `$ANDROID_HOME` is to insert with `/where-you-unpacked-the-sdk/sdk/` but my `android-studio` folder doesn't have an `sdk` folder at all. anyways I tried. no luck then I figured there's an `Android` folder at my home root `/home/et-ubuntu-pc/` and inside that `Android` folder it's a `SDK` folder so I tried using that too which is `/home/et-ubuntu-pc/Android/SDK` still no luck.

I am totally confused what I should be putting in my `$ANDROID_HOME` now.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: What's your sdk version?

Comment: @Anwar 2.1.3, downloaded 3-4 days ago

Comment: You said, "I went into /home/et-ubuntu-pc/App/android-studio/bin/ and ran /.studio.sh", what happened after you ran it?

Comment: You don't put `$ANDROID_HOME` in that file, but `export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/dir` . To test it you can use `echo $ANDROID_HOME` in the terminal.

Comment: @Anwar after I did that, the Android studio program loads up

Comment: @Timo what should I see in terminal when using `echo $ANDROID_HOME`? I keep seeing empty line in terminal

Comment: Then it will download and install the sdk for you. One thing to note, Android sdk and Android Studio are different things. Studio is where you code, that IDE will download sdk for you in first run.

Comment: @Anwar an ok I get what you mean then, so the `Android` folder which has the subfolder of `SDK` is where my sdk is installed but when I put `export ANDROID_HOME=/home/et-ubuntu-pc/Android/SDK` still no luck. though

Comment: May be studio couldn't installed or downloaded sdk. download it separately and extract at that location. it can be downloaded separately too

Comment: @Anwar in my `/home/et-ubuntu-pc/Android/Sdk` there are `add-ons`, `build-tools`, `platforms`, `platform-tools`, `SDK Readme.txt` does this still mean it's not installed / downloaded though?

Comment: @Anwar omg this is stupid. I should have try this days ago when having trouble.  I figured it's because I should put the `export .........` in `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

This is one stupid mistake.  `export $ANDROID_HOME` and `export $PATH` in `.bash_profile` is the reason why the path environment doesn't work.

I have to put both `$ANROID_HOME` AND `$PATH` into `.bashrc`

Comment: I should have detect this long ago. Because I knew Ubuntu ignore. bash_profie. +1 for solving own problem

Comment: @Anwar is this because of the new ubuntu? I always see people keep on saying use .bash_profile for ubuntu and pretty much no one complaint about it like I do ... hah

Comment: No. At least it was in 14.04 too! Ubuntu uses `.bashrc`.  For a new user, there will be no `.bash_profile`